# Priority queues implemented with avl in python

Tags: insert, max, priority-queue

Operations insert, delete, search for an AVL tree are implemented. How can I
implement the operations insert, maximum, extract-max, increase-key, decrease-key that a priority queue should support in python?

Comment: What language is this in? Also this question is very broad. Could you add what you have done to solve this as well as a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

An AVL tree is just a balanced binary search tree. The heap operations you've asked about can easily be implemented using the standard AVL operations.

- insert - Just insert into the AVL tree as you normally would.
- maximum - I assume you mean find-max. The maximum element in an AVL tree is the rightmost node. So just start at the root, traverse right pointers to the end, and return the leaf node.
- extract-max - Find the maximum node as above, and delete it.
- increase-key and decrease-key - Do a standard binary tree search to find the node you're interested in. Delete it from the tree. Modify the key. Re-insert into the tree.

Note that this won't be as efficient as a binary heap priority queue, but it will work.